# My custom cell does not display

Tags: iphone, ios, custom-cell

I have created a custom cell that contain a Label but when I added that in my Table View than it does not display, my view controller is not `TableViewController` I have seted Table View using IB and seted its delegate and datasource correctly.

I am doing this by:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    ExampleAppDataObject* theDataObject = [self theAppDataObject];
    return theDataObject.myAudio.count;
}


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        ExampleAppDataObject* theDataObject = [self theAppDataObject];

        NSString *destinationPath = [theDataObject.myAudio objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSArray *parts = [destinationPath componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

        NSString *filename = [parts lastObject];

        AudioInfoCell *cell = (AudioInfoCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[AudioInfoCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

        cell.audioName.text = filename;

        return cell;

    }
```

Comment: Do your numberOfSectionsInTableView: and tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method return the right numbers ?

Comment: post the method with code tableView:numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: check that you have some data in yourAry which you are manipulate in tableView

Comment: guys, it display cell but does not display my custom cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check how many row set in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` method

After set the custom cell like bellow..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AudioInfoCell *cell = (AudioInfoCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];


    // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AudioInfoCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (AudioInfoCell *) currentObject;
                break;

            }
        }
    }

    ExampleAppDataObject* theDataObject = [self theAppDataObject];

    NSString *destinationPath = [theDataObject.myAudio objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSArray *parts = [destinationPath componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

    NSString *filename = [parts lastObject];

    cell.audioName.text = filename;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why are you going through all that work?  That for-in loop will get run for every cell that is displayed, and will get run every time the user scrolls the TV.

Comment: it just alloc when cell is nil dude .. i use custem cell with this flow of code dude..

Comment: this give me error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<AudioTableViewController 0x73b0b30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key audioName.'"

Comment: AudioTableViewController is not UITableViewController i named it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

1. Make sure the reuse identifier matches what is in Interface Builder
2. Make sure your `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView`
   return the right numbers

Also - I don't use:

```
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[AudioInfoCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

for instantiating the cell.  That should be taken care of in the `AudioCell` `TableViewCell` subclass you have implemented.  An example of how I implement this kind of custom cell is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FlightPickerCell";
    FlightPickerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.tripIDLabel.text = @"Some TripID";
    cell.hospitalLabel.text = @"Some Hospital";
    cell.cityLabel.text = @"Some City";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: but should this FlightPickerCell reuse for another data,bcoz i want to use reuse this cell for different kind of data.

Comment: Yes.  That is just my implementation of a subclassed UITableViewCell.